# A timer to track time spent practicing Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this to record the time I spend practicing Python. I'll eventually add in functionality to visualize the data. I'd appreciate any feedback that will help me improve.

```
# timer.py - A timer to track time spent practicing python

from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime as Datetime
# used json b/c I wanted to practice it
import json
import os

# dict with all python practice options
options = ["Code Review",
           "Project",
           "Puzzles (Project Euler, Finxter, kaggle)",
           "Courses, Books, or Videos",
           "Read Docs"]


# Prompts user what type of practice they would like to do. User enters int.
def practice_choice():
    print("Pick a form of practice:\n")

    # print each option in options then ask user to select
    num = 1
    for option in options:
        print(str(num) + ". " + option)
        num += 1
    selection = input("\nPick a number: ")

    return options[int(selection) - 1]


def timer(selection):
    # store notes about practice session
    notes = input("Enter notes... ")

    # start timing session and get start time
    input("Hit Enter to begin practice...")
    start_dt = Datetime.now()

    # loop to allow for pausing. infinite loop that breaks when user clicks enter to stop session.
    var = 1
    total_so_far = 0
    while var == 1:
        pause_or_stop = input("Hit Enter to stop or space to pause...")

        # when user hits enters space char
        if pause_or_stop == ' ':

            # gets time session was paused. Calculates time practicing so far. Stores for later
            # Allows user to pause multiple times
            pause_dt = Datetime.now()
            total_so_far += int((start_dt - pause_dt) / timedelta(seconds=1))  # used sec for easier testing. 

            # resume on enter key and overwrites old start time
            input("Hit Enter to resume")
            start_dt = Datetime.now()

        # breaks if enter key
        elif pause_or_stop == '':
            break

        # catch bad input
        else:
            print("Key not recognized")

    # get stop time and find total time in minutes
    end_dt = Datetime.now()
    total_mins = int((end_dt - start_dt) / timedelta(seconds=1)) + total_so_far  # used sec for easier testing. 

    # add value to data[selection] dict. value is a list of datetime info, noes, total_minutes
    data[selection].append({'day': Datetime.now().strftime("%A"),  # %b %d %Y %H:%M),
                            'date': Datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y"),
                            'time': Datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
                            'notes': notes,
                            'minutes': total_mins})

    # convert dict to JSON object
    with open(target_file, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)


# prompt user for type of practice
choice = practice_choice()

# practice_log file with all practice sessions are stored
target_file = "practice_log.json"

# initialize data dict which will hold practice logs
data = {}

# creates json file if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(target_file):
    # top level values of json are created corresponding to practice type
    for each_item in options:
        data[each_item] = []
    with open(target_file, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)

# open json file and load into target_files
with open(target_file, 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# starts timer
timer(choice)
```

Answer (score 7):

***Ways to improve and redesign:***

I'll start with listing *inner* issues (duplication, redundant or over-complicated conditional/algorithms etc). Then I'll provide you with a new *Object-Oriented* approach as a more manageable, flexible and reliable.

- `options = [...]`. *"Practice options"* is better designed as a constant with immutable items (tuple):

  ```
  OPTIONS = ("Code Review",
          "Project",
          "Puzzles (Project Euler, Finxter, kaggle)",
          "Courses, Books, or Videos",
          "Read Docs")
  ```
- `practice_choice` function:
  Dragging `num` variable though the `for` loop is redundant and easily replaced with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) feature (with custom `start=` parameter):

  ```
  print('\n'.join(f'{i}. {option}' for i, option in enumerate(self.OPTIONS, 1)))
  ```
- `timer` function:
  `var` variable here:

  ```
  var = 1
  total_so_far = 0
  while var == 1:
      ...
  ```

  is redundant and it's not reassigned anywhere. Simply go with:

  ```
  while True:
      ...
  ```
- `total_so_far` variable is better named as `total_time`
- `Datetime.now()` is duplicated on constructing a dictionary of session info (notes, total minutes etc). 
  Instead, use `end_dt` from the nearest statement `end_dt = Datetime.now()` as it's already contains the current *datetime*.
- creating non-existent *target* file:
  filling `data` dict with:

  ```
  for each_item in options:
      data[each_item] = []
  ```

  is easily substituted with dict comprehension:

  ```
  data = {o: [] for o in self.OPTIONS}
  ```
- saving data

  ```
  with open(target_file, 'w') as json_file:
      json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)
  ```

  is extracted into a separate function/method with respective name

---

Now, the *Object-Oriented* **`PracticeTimer`** class with lot of benefits like:

- class constants
- encapsulated state/behavior
- dealing with target file: initializing/saving
- methods with specific responsibilities
- easy to extend

Underlying Class diagram:

[image]

---

```
# timer.py - A timer to track time spent practicing python

from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime as Datetime
import json
import os


class PracticeTimer:
    # practice options
    OPTIONS = ("Code Review",
               "Project",
               "Puzzles (Project Euler, Finxter, kaggle)",
               "Courses, Books, or Videos",
               "Read Docs")

    # practice_log file with all practice sessions are stored
    TARGET_FILE = "practice_log.json"

    def __init__(self):
        # creates json file if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(self.TARGET_FILE):
            # top level values of json are created corresponding to practice type
            data = {o: [] for o in self.OPTIONS}
            with open(self.TARGET_FILE, 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)

        # open json file and load session data
        with open(self.TARGET_FILE, 'r') as json_file:
            self._data = json.load(json_file)

        self._current_choice = None

    def practice_choice(self):
        """Prompts user to select practice item. User enters int."""
        print("Pick a form of practice:\n")

        # print options, then ask user to select
        print('\n'.join(f'{i}. {option}' for i, option in enumerate(self.OPTIONS, 1)))
        choice = input("\nPick a number: ")
        self._current_choice = self.OPTIONS[int(choice) - 1]
        return self._current_choice

    def _save_log(self):
        with open(self.TARGET_FILE, 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(self._data, json_file, indent=4)

    def run(self):
        self.practice_choice()

        # store notes about practice session
        notes = input("Enter notes... ")

        # start timing session and get start time
        input("Hit Enter to begin practice...")
        start_dt = Datetime.now()

        # loop to allow for pausing. Infinite loop that breaks when user clicks enter to stop session.
        total_time = 0
        while True:
            pause_or_stop = input("Hit Enter to stop or space to pause...")

            # when user hits enters space char
            if pause_or_stop == ' ':

                # gets time session was paused. Calculates time practicing so far. Stores for later
                # Allows user to pause multiple times
                pause_dt = Datetime.now()
                total_time += int((start_dt - pause_dt) / timedelta(seconds=1))  # used sec for easier testing.

                # resume on enter key and overwrites old start time
                input("Hit Enter to resume")
                start_dt = Datetime.now()

            # breaks if enter key
            elif pause_or_stop == '':
                break
            # catch bad input
            else:
                print("Key not recognized")

        # get stop time and find total time in minutes
        end_dt = Datetime.now()
        total_mins = int((end_dt - start_dt) / timedelta(seconds=1)) + total_time  # used sec for easier testing.

        # add info to the current session (as a list of datetime info, notes, total_minutes)
        self._data[self._current_choice].append({'day': end_dt.strftime("%A"),  # %b %d %Y %H:%M),
                                                 'date': end_dt.strftime("%m-%d-%y"),
                                                 'time': end_dt.strftime("%H:%M"),
                                                 'notes': notes,
                                                 'minutes': total_mins})

        self._save_log()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_timer = PracticeTimer()
    p_timer.run()
```

Comment: Nice use of a class. I was contemplating whether I should add it, but decided against it in the end. Good to see that it is represented nevertheless!

Comment: @Graipher, Thanks, I appreciate that.

Comment: (`# used sec for easier testing.`, if you put these in a row just above the code it refers to, you won't have to scroll right here on SO.  :)  )

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate this. A couple questions so far:
- At the top, you use self.OPTIONS in the practice_choice function. I shouldn't be able to use self until I implemented the PracticeTimer class, correct?

- In practice_choice, why do you use \n in the join? Doesn't that separate each character with a newline?

Comment: @engineer.lisa, welcome. 1) `OPTIONS` attribute will be accessed and shared across all `PracticeTimer` instances, though it resides in the class namespace. Python will take care of that due to *name resolution*. If you need to visually point out the exact binding - you may specify it as `PracticeTimer.OPTIONS`; 2) *Doesn't that separate each character with a newline?* - No, that one-liner with single `print` call is a replacement of your `for` loop with multiple `print` calls, it concatenates each "option" with a newline `\n` to get the needed output

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Code Review! This is a nice first question. Here are a few comments:

- Documenting your code is nice. Comments are an OK way to do it, but one hard part of documentation is already obvious in your first comment:

  ```
  # dict with all python practice options
  options = ["Code Review", ...]
  ```

  Keeping code and documentation in line is hard. You say it is a `dict`, but it is actually a `list`.

  For some of your other comments, you should take a look at [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), the description of the `docstring`. This allows you to set a documentation string which can be interactively retrieved using `help(...)` and which is picked up by many automatic documentation tools. For your function `practice_choice` this could be as simple as moving the comment inside:

  ```
  def practice_choice():
      """Prompts user what type of practice they would like to do. User enters int."""
      ...
  ```
- The standard library is your friend. It has many built-in functions and many more helpful modules. It never hurts trying to learn as many of them as possible.

  Instead of

  ```
  num = 1
  for option in options:
      print(str(num) + ". " + option)
      num += 1
  ```

  You can write:

  ```
  for num, option in enumerate(options, 1):
      print(f"{num}. {option}")
  ```

  This uses [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (using the optional second argument to start at one) and the new (Python 3.7+) [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

  Similarly, when the file is newly created, you have to create empty lists so that later the calls to `data.append` don't fail. Instead you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is also in the standard library:

  ```
  from collections import defaultdict

  data = defaultdict(list)
  ```

  This will call the given constructor, here `list`, whenever a key does not yet exist, giving you an empty list.
- If you are writing an interactive program, it pays off to define a generic enough function to handle user input. Common features you want is type adherence, allowed values, ranges, or even generic validator functions, and prompting the user until a valid input is given. This is how such a function could look like in your case:

  ```
  def ask_user(message, type_=str, valid=None):
      while True:
          user_input = input(message)
          try:
              user_input = type_(user_input)
          except ValueError:
              print(f"Wrong type, expected {type_}")
              continue
          if valid is not None:
              if callable(valid) and valid(user_input):
                  return user_input
              elif user_input in valid:
                  return user_input
              print("Invalid input.")
  ```

  This can be used in many places in your code:

  ```
  selection = ask_user("\nPick a number: ", int, range(1, len(options) + 1))

  msg = "\n".join(f"{num}. {option}" for num, option in enumerate(options, 1))
  choice = options[ask_user(msg, int, range(1, len(options) + 1)) - 1]

  ask_user("Hit Enter to begin practice...", valid="")

  pause_or_stop = ask_user("Hit Enter to stop or space to pause...", valid=" ")    # or `valid=["", " "]`, but `"" in " "` returns True
  ```
- Try to separate your functions that do something from input and output. You have the core functionality of the function, a pausable timer, and then you have taking notes associated with it, saving it to a file, adding metadata. I would put these things in separate functions.

  Along with that, you should put your main code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), to allow importing from this file without executing the code.

  Here is one way to do it. This is a pausable timer as a generator that `yield`s the beginning and end of every section

  ```
  def timer():
      start = datetime.now()
      print("Timer started")
      while True:
          user_input = ask_user("Hit Enter to stop or space to pause...", valid=" ")
          yield start, datetime.now()
          if user_input != " ":
              return
          if ask_user("Hit Enter to resume, anything else to abort", valid=" ") == "":
              start = datetime.now()
          else:
              return
  ```

  Which can be used like this:

  ```
  for t0, t1 in timer():
      total_mins = int((t1 - t0).total_seconds() // 60)
      ...
  ```

  The whole `main` function could then be:

  ```
  def main():
      options = ["Code Review",
                 "Project",
                 "Puzzles (Project Euler, Finxter, kaggle)",
                 "Courses, Books, or Videos",
                 "Read Docs"]
      choice = practice_choice(options)
      notes = input("Enter notes... ")

      file_name = "practice_log.json"
      if os.path.isfile(file_name):
          with open(file_name) as f:
              data = defaultdict(list, json.loads(f))
      else:
          data = defaultdict(list)

      for t0, t1 in timer():
          total_mins = int((t1 - t0).total_seconds() // 60)
          print(f"Worked on {choice} for {total_mins} minutes")
          data[choice].append({'day': t1.strftime("%A"),
                               'date': t1.strftime("%m-%d-%y"),
                               'time': t1.strftime("%H:%M"),
                               'notes': notes,
                               'minutes': total_mins})
          with open(file_name, 'w') as json_file:
              json.dump(dict(data), json_file, indent=4)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      while True:
          main()
  ```

  Note that `practice_choice` now takes the options as an argument. I also made the main program repeat, in case you want to start the next timer immediately.

  I used `os.path.isfile` instead of `os.path.exists`, because the latter is also true for directories. I don't know why you would *want* to create a directory called `"practice_log.json"`, but it can happen accidentally and then your code would crash.
- Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Your code follows it almost everywhere, but the one place it doesn't is where the standard library also doesn't.

  You imported it `as Datetime`, PEP8 would recommend `DateTime`, but it is just called `datetime`. I would either use the name it is given (which happened before the naming convention existed AFAIK), or use the fully PEP8 compliant name.

Comment: Thanks for all this feedback. Still going though it but wanted to say thanks. Also, I'll read the docstring PEP as you recommend.